# JPA: Automatically refresh mapped entities from technical key

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

I have a unidirectional mapped @OneToMany relationship in one of my entites. Let's say something like this (not complete - just for the idea):

```
@Entity
public class Contract {

  @OneToMany
  @JoinColumn(name="...", referencedColumnName="...")
  Product product;
```

Now, as step one, I load all products from my backend, then I load all contracts from a different interface. That latter interface passes over only the technical key of the product. At the moment I load all products, put them in a map as key and object and then put them into a new Contract when loaded. Is that really the way to go?
I experimented for a while with setting equals in Product to the technical key only and hopped that JPA would do the trick when merging the Contract entity - but this was not successful.

Any hints are welcome.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What's your question? I don't understand what you're asking, and what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: LoadedContract lc = myBackend.getContracts().get(0); Product p = new Product(); product.setKey(lc.getKey()); Contract c = new Contract(); c.setProduct(p); em.persist(c); Now I would expect - if equals is implemented so that Product is compared by the technical key - that contract is persisted with a valid product already existing in the database instead of creating a new one. Is that any clearer? Otherwise I will rephrase the question... Thanks.

Comment: JPA coesn't care about equals(). It uses the ID of the entity to uniquely identify it among the other ones. Use find() or getReference() to get an existing Product having a given ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood from your example, you have a Contract entity, which references several product entities, and you want to know how to reflect that in JPA-Java. If so, then you only need to add the products to the Contract's product list. Remember, JPA transform tables into objects, so any relationship will take the form of a class member. If the relationship is multiple, then the class member will be a collection (a list, for example). Then, you can:

-Create a new collection of products, add the products, and then set the contract's collection of product with this new collection, a good approach if the contract has no products:

```
List<Products> listProducts = new ArrayList<Products>();
//add the products
contract.setProductList(listProducts);
```

-Recover the collection of products of the contract and then add the desired products, a good approach if the contract has previous products:

```
contract.getProductList().add(product);
```

In any case, you'll need to commit the changes. Take in mind you'll need to persist the parent entity in the relationship, in this case, contract.